# IFormFile unable to get file (null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, model-view-controller

I get an error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why is it null? Please help resolve it!!

EDIT: The error line is

```
themobilesuits.PicFile = Path.GetFileName(thePic.FileName);
```

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(TheMobileSuit themobilesuits, IFormFile thePic)
{
    DbSet<TheMobileSuit> dbs = _dbContext.TheMobileSuit;


    themobilesuits.PicFile = Path.GetFileName(thePic.FileName);

    dbs.Add(themobilesuits);

    if (_dbContext.SaveChanges() == 1)
    {
        string fname = "Images/" + themobilesuits.PicFile;
        if (UploadFile(thePic, fname))
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = "New Order Added!";
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }                              
    else
        TempData["Msg"] = "Error.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

private bool UploadFile(IFormFile ufile, string fname)
{
    if (ufile.Length > 0)
    {
        string fullpath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, fname);
        using (var fileStream =
                   new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            ufile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


View:

    <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Photo:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="file" name="thePic"
                           class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Well, either themobilesuits or thePic is null.

Comment: thePic is null.

Comment: themobilesuits is able to capture the data from View.

Comment: Please share the code for the client where the POST occurs. The HTML or Razor or whatever front end technology you're using.

Comment: Matt U I shared the client side. See above

Comment: Does changing your code to `[FromForm]IFormFile thePic` make a difference?

Comment: [FromForm]IFormFile does not make a difference. error is still the same - null.

Comment: try getting the file like this, var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

Answer (score 1):

i THINK you have not used :
 enctype = "multipart/form-data"  in  tag.
eg:

```
<form method=post action="..."enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same error, and I've fix it.

(1)In your View --

```
<input type="file" name="**thePic**" class="form-control" />
```

(2)In your Controller and Action --

```
public IActionResult Add(TheMobileSuit themobilesuits, IFormFile **thePic**)
```

{

(3) In ViewModel , your property Name is **thePic** ,too .

** These three parameters' NAME must be THE SAME.....**
(Your name is "thePic")

I've spend 4 hours to find this problem.
Wish it's helpful to you.  Thanks.